# How to use Mozilla HTML objects in react JavaScript

Tags: reactjs

```
const filereader=new FileReader()
```

filereader.onload (e)=> (e.target.file)}
const file= document.getElementById ("filename").files[0];
return (

)

I found this from Mozilla but I think this not working with react, I am trying to create upload files by fetch or by post
so biggest question is that was HTML so what a best and effective source for react for search these types of methods or do I need to go with change Mozilla HTML to react but by that console not showing errors its like blank screen, for effective learning every line of code should be understood

Comment: you can have a `ref` to the input element from where you can get the DOM properties with it and rest is the same ....

Comment: class uploadfiles extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.Filereader = React.createFilereader();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.Filereader} />;
  }
}   somthing like that?

Comment: added an e.g. its nothing different if you are using class components, just the syntax changes ...

Comment: Could you please add some punctuation and formatting to your question? It is really hard to read and understand what exactly you are asking. If you would like some help in writing questions please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> A basic e.g to upload file, you can check more here in
> [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file)

```js
// Get a hook function
const {
  useState
} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState(null);
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const submitFile = () => {
    if (!file) return;

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('avatar', file);

    fetch('https://api.imgur.com/3/image', {  // replace your API here
        method: 'POST', 
        body: formData
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('Success:', result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  };

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    input onChange = {
      (e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])
    }
    type = "file" / > < br / >
    <
    button onClick = {
      submitFile
    } > Upload File < /button> <
    /div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render( <
  App / >
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```