# How to upload image to Rest API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hi stackoverflow community! I need some explanation about sending images to **Rest API**. A little background: I have a simple registration system on the site (written on React + Typescript) and I decided to add loading the user's avatar during registration and then sending all the data (including name, gender, phone number, and so on) to the **Rest API** (in this case it is a ***MockAPI*** service).

If there are no problems with sending common data (like name, surname and other's), then there are difficulties with sending an avatar. I tried several methods, including formData and several third-party services, but they did not bring the desired result.

How can I send an avatar to the **Rest API** and then use it with the rest of the data on the site?

P/S
Totally agree - I should have added the code! I want to say right away that this is just an example and a small part of the code.

```
const SignUp = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState("");
  const [avatar, setAvatar] = React.useState(null);

  const submitNewUser = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('avatar', avatar);

    fetch('https://*MY_HASH*mockapi.io/*MY_FILE*', {
        method: 'POST', 
        body: formData
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('Success:', result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.name}>
        <span>Type your Username</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" value={username} onChange={(e: any) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.avatar}>
        <label htmlFor="file"><i><BsFillCloudUploadFill/></i>Upload your Avatar</label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file" onChange={(e: any) => setAvatar([...e.target.files])} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

From the API, I received a successful response, but in the file itself on the API there was the following:

```
[{"File":{},"id":"1"}]
```

It's just an empty object and id.

Comment: A basic e.g. that I have included [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73769962/11737596) if it helps, you can add rest of the data to `FormData` ...

Comment: It is possible to do this, and you mentioned some options, but you need to share the code you wrote this this and explain how it failed

Comment: Better if you could share the more details like the Rest API signature or accepting parameters like info here to provide a solid answer

Comment: Thanks for your's attention - code added!

Comment: have you tried adding `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` to your request headers:
`fetch('...', {..., headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}})`

Comment: @Ismail_Aj I just tried to add headers - I got the same result: an empty object and an id.